# How to use conditional if statement to change element of row is python

Tags: python, if-statement

I need help with conditional if statement and row update.

```
data = [("aa",1,.500,1), ("bb",3,000,1), ("cc",2,.750,1)]


    foo = []
    bar = []
    Rdata = 15
    for row in data:
            if row[1] < Rdata:
                foo.append(row) # creates foo table 

    #need help after this point             
    for row in foo: 
        if row[2] > 0:
            bar.append(row)
```

How Do i create output table

```
bar = [("aa1.5",1,.500,1), ("bb3",3,000,1), ("cc2.75",2,.750,1)]
```

Edit: Better example of dataSet...

```
data2 = [(3,4,6,"aa","ab",1,.500,1,2,3), (1,2,1,"bb","ba",3,000,1,2,2), (4,5,5,"cc","cb",2,.750,1,2,3)]
```

Need

```
   data2 = [(3,4,6,"aa1.5","ab1.5",1,.500,1,2,3), (1,2,1,"bb3","ba3",3,000,1,2,2), (4,5,5,"cc2.75","cb2.75",2,.750,1,2,3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [('%s%s' % (x[0], x[1] + x[2]),) + x[1:] for x in data]
[('aa1.5', 1, 0.5, 1), ('bb3', 3, 0, 1), ('cc2.75', 2, 0.75, 1)]
```

Comment: works for above, but whatif element 'aa' is in position 5 out of 10.

Comment: Then you change `x[0]` to `x[4]`. Indexing is still indexing.

Comment: I added dataset 2 for better example of real data... My thought was to use if but I like indexing better.

Comment: I think slice before and slice after, right? I actually have 2 "aa" sets to do.